# Django insert empty inline style

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to learn django and had create a simple website but the problem is when I try to insert bootstrap the layout is display incorrectly and then I found out the problem is with this empty:

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

which automatic inserted( I had tried to insert empty html and the style is still there) and here is my django template html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        {% include 'news/includes/header.html' %}
        {% block title %}
            <title>News</title>
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
    <body>

    {% include 'news/includes/nav.html' %}

    <div class="row">
        <div id="top-ads" class="col-md-12">fsdfsdf</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="left-ads" class="col-md-2">sdf</div>
        <div id="container" class="col-md-8">
                        {% block container %}
                            {% if news_list %}
                                <ul>
                                    {% for new in news_list %}
                                        <li> <a href="{% url 'news:new' new.id %}"> {{ new.title }}</a></li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div id="right-ads" class="col-md-2">yodsfddf</div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="footer" class="col-md-12">sdfsdfsd</div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image: output image]

edit:
OK this is getting weirder and weirder if I try to move the `<style>` tag even I drop at the same position all the layout work again. I surrender

Comment: Django does not insert anything in your templates. You must have another template (such as the ones you `include`) that has that empty style tags.

Comment: Did you check the file `news/includes/header.html`?

Comment: Have you linked the boostrap css to any of your html files?

Comment: I had included in the header.html but I already try to delete all the code in base.html but the style still coming up

Comment: I had check the header.html it is only have the link to bootstrap that it